# Best way to copy a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a struct `Y` with a vector of type `X`, I would like to ask whether in this case assign is the best solution or copy would be better? Should I resize `y.xVec`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct X {
  X(int x):x_(x)
  {}
  int x_;
};

struct Y {
  std::vector<X>xVec;
};

int main()
{
    X x1(1);
    X x2(2);
    std::vector<X> v = {x1,x2};
    
    Y y;
    y.xVec.assign(v.begin(), v.end());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest code is the best here:

```
y.xVec = v;
```

Or if you don't need `v` anymore:

```
y.xVec = std::move(v);
```

Or if you will use `v` again but starting from empty:

```
y.xVec = std::exchange(v, {});
```

`exchange()` is better than `move()` if you need to use `v` again, because it leaves `v` in its default-constructed state (empty), rather than the unspecified state given by `move()`.

Comment: One may say that the simplest code here would be `Y y = {v};`.

Comment: In what situation  is indicated to use assign?

Comment: @Cameron121341: When you want to assign from something which is not another vector.   For example `std::list` or `std::set`.  Then `assign()` is appropriate, and the methods I listed in this answer wouldn't compile.

Comment: @Cameron121341 `assign` takes a range. That range can be a complete `std::vector`, but it can also be just a part of a `std::vector` or even (part of) some other container.